# Type alias on right side of using alias directive

Tags: c#, using-directives

I wanted to do

```
namespace n
{
    using TupT = Tuple<TextBox, string, Func<bool>, string>;

    // Doesn't compile
    // using DicT = Dictionary<Button, TupT>;

    // Have to repeat tuple definition: cumbersome and error prone
    using DicT = Dictionary<Button, Tuple<TextBox, Func<bool>, string>>;
    // ...
}
```

This is forbidden by par. 9.3.1 of this language spec: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx. Generally, type aliases are not visible to other using alias directives. (Generics are actually not an issue, but the demand for aliasing occurs frequently with generics because the type denotations can become complex.)

Why is that so?

Edit: Yes, I know: I can do it differently in a myriad ways. But I'm specifically wondering why I cannot do it this way ;-)

Comment: It might be better to create a class that encapsulates the data you are putting into the `Tuple` to simplify your generics and your code in general.

Comment: Maybe simply because they didn't think it was worth spending time in? I think the number of side effects and scenarios to work out don't weigh up to the gain.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I can easily imagine that it actually took extra implementation effort in the compiler to *forbid* it. C's typedefs seem dirt simple to implement.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I never implemented it so I do not know for sure but it seems straightforward and orthogonal to the rest of the language.

Comment: I can imagine it's because C# language designers wanted to leave outside as much weirdness as possible, which is the thing you would strive to do if you ever release any piece of documentation to public.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this restriction is simply to rule out having to worry about situations like the following in the compiler.

```
using X = C<Y>;
using Y = C<X>;
class C<T> { }
```

Of course the problem is that `X` is `C<Y>` is `C<C<X>>` is `C<C<C<Y>>>` is ...

If the language restriction was looser, disallowing only circular using alias directives, the compiler could feasibly handle that. I think this is just a feature with very low priority - the C# language team only has so much time to design and implement features.

If you find yourself utilizing using alias directives very often, it's an indicator that your common using alias directive should really be made into a class.  I'm sure `Tuple<TextBox, string, Func<bool>, string>` isn't nearly as descriptive as a tiny four-property model class.

Comment: I do agree with your suggestion for a simple class (you may not believe it but it occured to me all on my own). But I'm asking this on StackOverflow and not on CodeReview, for a reason ;-).

Comment: As to the cyclical dependency problem: This can happen on many occasions in a program, can't it? Compiler writers have to catch cyclical dependencies all the time, e.g. `struct T1 { T2 t2; }; struct T2 { T1 t1; }`

Comment: @PeterSchneider That's exactly right, but in that instance it *is* extremely common for people to want to reference structs in other structs. Therefore the feature to be less restrictive on inter-struct references and check only for circular dependencies had high priority for the C# language team. I can guarantee there isn't any deep philosophical reason using alias directives can't reference each other. It's just a feature that wasn't included. :)